# Want to print when item is not found

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     struct Item item[MAX_ITEMS];
     int size = 0, menu, loop = 0, index = 0, number;

...    

}else if(menu == 2){ // If user presses 2, add to inventory
        printf("Please input a SKU number: ");
        scanf("%d",&item[index].sku_);
        printf("Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d",&item[index].quantity_);

        for(int i =0; i <= 10; i++){
            if(item[index].sku_ == item[i].sku_){
                printf("The item exists in the repository, quanity is updated.\n");
            }
        }
        index++;
```

I have sort of figured out how to find an item in the array. The problem I'm having is implementing:

```
printf("Price: ");
scanf("%f",&item[index].price_);
```

into the code. What I'm trying to do is to put those 2 lines of code IF the for loop could not find the item.

Comment: You need to edit this down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, any attempt to answer this question would be a wild guess at best.

Comment: *C++ Shopping Cart Array* -- Where is the "C++" in any of this code?  Looks like all `C` to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to track whether the item has been found. With an array and standard iteration you need to search the whole list. This is pseudocode, but you should get the idea.

```
bool found = false;
for each (SKU in list...) {
   if (SKU == itemSKU) {found = true;}
}
if (!found) {
   /// Your code here
}
```